# Is there a scalability issue in having a one-to-many relationship between participants and conversation?

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship, scalability, erd

I have a database design as shown in following entity-relationship diagram (ERD):

https://app.dbdesigner.net/designer/schema/0-social_media-00a3405c-0bcd-4809-9f8e-e86c1b8e5f33

I was wondering if I should have a **one-to-many** relationship between `Participants` and `Conversation`.

#### Issue: need many joins

The issue is that we need to make a join every time we want to get the `id` of the `Participants` of a `Conversation` to broadcast `Messages`.

Not only that, but we also need the `content` of the `Messages`,  meaning we need to make two joins between three tables.

#### Questions

- Is there a more scalable solution for this?
- Is there any bottleneck issues?
- Is there anything else wrong with the table aside that as an added bonus?

Comment: In fact the relationship would be **many-to-many**, do you agree?

Comment: So would you implement a table containing the id of participants and the id of conversation as foreign keys between the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Scalable because:

If one conversation attracts more and more Users (in their role as participants), you simply have to add rows in the table `Participants`. Imagine the conversation has a members-list, it's called `Participants`.

If one User account was deleted, you simply have to search for all his records (associated conversations) in table `Participants` and delete them as well.

Both cases mean only a modification of `Participants`, whereas the conversation remains untouched.

#### Associative Entity

This membership or relationship of `User` to `Conversation` is **bridged** by a so-called *associative relationship*, *associative table* or [associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity). Means one `User` can attend (participate in) 0 or many `Conversations`, vice-versa one `Conversation` can have (at least) one (the creator) or many participating `Users`.

So the entity/table `Participants` acts like a **bridge**: connecting two sides/perspectives.

#### Broadcast Example

User `A` wants to broadcast a message to the channel/conversation `1`. Now the system needs to determine all recipients. So look **only within table Participants** for the conversation `1` and find their attending Users `A`, `B` and `C`. All except the sender `A` should receive the broadcast: `B` and `C`.

There was **no join** involved. A **simple query**: `SELECT user_id FROM participants WHERE conversation_id = 1 AND user_id <> 'A'`. Given the `Message` and assuming that `user_id`s can be used directly as destination (email-address, phone-number, etc.), the system can immediately send the broadcast out.